# Chromecast: Gradle: package android.support.v7.media does not exist

Tags: gradle, android-studio, chromecast

I'm running into a small issue while trying to build a sample Chromecast app. I can't seem to resolve android.support.v7.media in order to use the MediaRouteSelector class. My gradle file dependencies look like this:

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
    compile files('libs/GoogleCastSdkAndroid.jar')
}

and the only v7 lib I have in my sdk folder is for a gallery grid. Anyone happen to know where I can find this lib, or what line I need to add to my build file in order to find the correct package?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

So the SDK that was being used was /Applications/Android Studio.app/sdk, and the v7 mediarouter files were in there but not being used. I ended up just copying the jar and placing it into the libs folder, then using compile files( 'libs/android-support-v7-mediarouter.jar'); in my gradle.build file.

Scratch that, now it crashes on inflating the MediaRouteButton xml. May just uninstall Android Studio and try again. Just frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

The less intensive way to resolve this is to open your Android SDK manager, and select to download/install SDK 4.1, 4.1.1 API level 16.
Then restart your IDE (Android Studio or Eclipse I assume).

Comment: Nope, did that and it's still a no go :(